# Woocomerce App on Ionic loads same product on homepage when doing a load more

Tags: android, ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

i run a woocommerce store and i need an app for mobile users which brought me to ionic framework node.js and cordova apps. I have since been able to modify a few apps with different templates by editing its consumerkey and consumer secret keys with same as my woocommerce api.

This apps works but they all have the same problem.

Homepage: 10 Products Loads on opening of APP the a Load More Text which is suppose to automatically load next 10 products but ends up loading same products already loaded.

Search: if i search for any products, it shows me 10 results and as i scroll 10. It loads same 10 results instead of other products not already loaded.

Pls help me check the video attached below to understand more.

here is an unlisted Youtube video to make my explanation better [Video of my ionic apps](https://youtu.be/ZP1pyUbwBI8)

Comment: Could you edit your question  and tells us what exactly your question is?

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass page variable to woocommerce 
like this

```
this.page = 1;
this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products?page=" + this.page)
....
this.page++;
```

every time you call products it will send 10 products to you